# Tricky Python string literals in passing parameter to timeit.Timer() function

Tags: python, string-literals, timeit

I'm having a hard time with the setup statement in Python's timeit.Timer(stmt, setup_stmt). I appreciate any help to get me out of this tricky problem:

So my sniplet looks like this:

```
def compare(string1, string2):
    # compare 2 strings

if __name__ = '__main__':
    str1 = "This string has \n several new lines \n in the middle"
    str2 = "This string hasn't any new line, but a single quote ('), in the middle"

    t = timeit.Timer('compare(p1, p2)', "from __main__ import compare; p1=%s, p2=%s" % (str1,str2))
```

I don't know how to escape the metacharacter in the variable str1, str2 without changing their meaning in the setup statement:

```
"from __main__ import compare; p1=%s, p2=%s" % (str1,str2)
```

I tried various combination but always have the following errors:
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning single-quoted string
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider This as an alternative.

```
t = timeit.Timer('compare(p1, p2)', "from __main__ import compare; p1=%r; p2=%r" % (str1,str2))
```

The `%r` uses the repr for the string, which Python always quotes and escapes correctly.

EDIT: Fixed code by changing a comma to a semicolon; the error is now gone.

Comment: I tried it and had a SyntaxError: can't assign to literal. Thank you anyway.

Comment: The problem was that he put a comma where a semicolon was required.  Try it again with what's there now and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother quoting the strings at all?  Just use them directly.
ie. change your last line to:

```
t = timeit.Timer('compare(str1, str2)', "from __main__ import compare, str1, str2")
```